# Parametrized Textbox controls in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I want to set properties of a Textbox control(like Readonly or Mandatory etc.), based on a parameter passed in another field. E.g. If the status is "Employed",the Textbox control "Salary" will become mandatory; else it will not be mandatory. The conditions can also be passed by an SQL query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In simple manner, you can do this with jquery. i.e. On the basis of some status you need to identify in jquery and you can set the Textbox validation.
But You can't change the server side property.

In Complex way, by server side code,
On the basis of status you can apply the textbox value but you need to refer the page to execute the server side code. or you can use updatepanel for that textbox which can help you and only refresh the textbox section and execute your server side code.

Hope this helps.